# How can I "zip" two arrays in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I want to zip two arrays, like [how Ruby does it](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-zip), but in PowerShell. Here's a hypothetical operator (I know we're probably talking about some kind of goofy pipeline, but I just wanted to show an example output).

```
PS> @(1, 2, 3) -zip @('A', 'B', 'C')
@(@(1, 'A'), @(2, 'B'), @(3, 'C'))
```

Comment: https://www.automatedops.com/blog/2017/02/09/working-with-the-collection-extension-methods-3-of-3/

Comment: Do you want to keep them as arrays (array of arrays), or just all values as one array?

Comment: I do NOT want to merge the arrays. I need the elements as pairs for later processing, hopefully in a pipeline.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe That looks like an answer that is better than rolling your own function

Comment: `[Linq.Enumerable]::Zip((1, 2, 3), ('A', 'B', 'C'), [Func[Object, Object, Object[]]]{,$args})`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's nothing built-in and it's probably not recommended to "roll your own" function. So, we'll take the LINQ Zip method and wrap it up.

```
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Zip((1, 2, 3), ('A', 'B', 'C'), [Func[Object, Object, Object[]]]{ ,$args })
```

That works, but it's not pleasant to work with over time. We can wrap the function (and include that in our profile?).

```
function Select-Zip {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        $First,
        $Second,
        $ResultSelector = { ,$args }
    )

    [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Zip($First, $Second, [Func[Object, Object, Object[]]]$ResultSelector)
}
```

And you can call it simply:

```
PS> Select-Zip -First 1, 2, 3 -Second 'A', 'B', 'C'
1
A
2
B
3
C
```

With a non-default result selector:

```
PS> Select-Zip -First 1, 2, 3 -Second 'A', 'B', 'C' -ResultSelector { param($a, $b) "$a::$b" }
1::A
2::B
3::C
```

I leave the pipeline version as an exercise to the astute reader :)

```
PS> 1, 2, 3 | Select-Zip -Second 'A', 'B', 'C'
```

Comment: Nicely done. As for a hypothetical operator: while not an operator, an enhancement was proposed to the `foreach` _statement_, along the lines of `foreach ($elementFromArray1, $elementFromArray2 in @(1, 2, 3), @('A', 'B', 'C')) { ... }` - unfortunately, it was declined - see [GitHub issue #14732](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14732)

Comment: With PS 7.x we can also use the `Linq.Enumerable.Zip` overload that outputs tuples, alleviating the need to pass a function: `[Linq.Enumerable]::Zip( [int[]](1, 2, 3), [string[]]('A', 'B', 'C'))`. Note that the arrays must be typed because otherwise PowerShell can't find the correct overload.

Comment: If you don't know the types of the arrays beforehand, casting to `[object[]]` arrays also works: `[Linq.Enumerable]::Zip( [object[]](1, 2, 3), [object[]]('A', 'B', 'C') )`

Comment: Using powershell core, if my arrays are typed coming into a function, it's simply `[Linq.Enumerable]::Zip($arr1, $arr2)`

Answer (score 4):

```bsh
# Multiple arrays
$Sizes = @("small", "large", "tiny")
$Colors = @("red", "green", "blue")
$Shapes = @("circle", "square", "oval")

# The first line "zips"
$Sizes | ForEach-Object { $i = 0 }{ @{size=$_; color=$Colors[$i]; shape=$Shapes[$i]}; $i++ } `
 | ForEach-Object { $_.size + " " + $_.color + " " + $_.shape }
```

Outputs:

```
small red circle
large green square
tiny blue oval
```