# Merge two arrays of objects

Tags: arrays, powershell, join, merge

I am having two variables which are both system.array type.
I want to merge them and get the output in Out-grid view.

The first Variable is $out

echo $out

```
number            : CTASK19496
state             : Assigned
User Name         : Ana
CI Name           :
comments          :
work_notes        :
short_description : Implementation Task
opened_at         : 24/11/2020 01:37:40


number            : CTASK000501
state             : Assigned
User Name         : Ranjay 
CI Name           :
comments          :
work_notes        :
short_description : Implementation Task
opened_at         : 24/11/2020 03:50:16


number            : CTASK000169
state             : Assigned
User Name         : Dan
CI Name           :
comments          :
work_notes        :
short_description : configure the full 
opened_at         : 25/11/2020 14:47:1
```

The second Variable is $data

echo $data

```
end_date
--------
10/11/2020 23:59:59
25/11/2020 23:59:59
26/11/2020 23:59:59
```

code I tried is

```
$Shortened = $out + $out1 | ForEach-Object {
$_ | Select-Object number, end_date
 }
```

$Shortened | Format-Table -AutoSize

Output I am getting is

```
 number        end_date
------        --------
CTASK19496
CTASK000501
CTASK000169
              03/12/2020 23:59:59
              04/12/2020 23:59:00
              30/11/2020 21:30:00
```

Output what I want is as below

```
 number        end_date
------        --------
CTASK19496    03/12/2020 23:59:59
CTASK000501   04/12/2020 23:59:00
CTASK000169   30/11/2020 21:30:00
```

Comment: if the 2 arrays are in sync, you can iterate thru one and buld a `[PSCustomObject]` with the iterated collection and the same index number in the other collection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I "zip" two arrays in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122000/how-can-i-zip-two-arrays-in-powershell)

Comment: To apply [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44055098/7571258) to your data: `Select-Zip $out $data -ResultSelector { param($a, $b) [PSCustomObject]@{ number = $a.number; end_date = $b.end_date }}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two CSV's - Add CSV as another Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574792/combine-two-csvs-add-csv-as-another-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ass [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) commented, it's assumed each row in each array are related. You can use a for loop like this

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $out.count; $i++)
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        number   = $out[$i].number
        end_date = $out1[$i].end_date
    }
}
```

output

```
number      end_date           
------      --------           
CTASK19496  03/12/2020 23:59:59
CTASK000501 04/12/2020 23:59:00
CTASK000169 30/11/2020 21:30:00
```

Just capture to a variable and then send to `Out-GridView`

```
$output = for($i = 0; $i -lt $out.count; $i++)
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        number   = $out[$i].number
        end_date = $out1[$i].end_date
    }
}

$output | Out-GridView
```

Comment: @Doug-this is what i was looking for. Thanks